# Why would I not want to use Apple Java?

Tags: macos, java

Being fairly new to the Mac platform, I was wondering why, when [downloading Charles web debugging application](http://www.charlesproxy.com/latest-release/download.do), they would offer an alternative download if you do not want to use Apple Java?

What are the potential down sides?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Apple's version of Java has not been updated since Oracle bought Sun, and as such is old (Java 6 is the last version of Apple Java, and it will not be receiving any more updates).

While Java is just a programming language and using an old version is fine if your software works on it, Java also comes with support for Java Web Applets in browsers, which must be kept up to date in order to be secure when running untrusted applets from websites. For this reason, OS X users should use a recent version of Java 8 from Oracle and **not** use Apple Java to make sure that the Web Applet support doesn't have security vulnerabilities in it.

If you explicitly disable Java Web Applet support in your web browsers, then it doesn't really matter which version of Java you use as long as it meets the minimum requirements of the Java application that you're trying to run.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of products which do not support Java VM's other than Oracle's implementation. There are also Java VM's out there that have propietary extensions which might be necessary to run a specific application.

Believe it or not, there are even users/developers which have prejudices against some alternative implementations.